# unbinding scope property in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope, unbind

Is there a way to unbind the reference when we are assigning values from scope properties?

For example I have $scope.X and $scope.Y. At some point in my function I want to assign the value of $scope.Y at that time to $scope.X:

```
$scope.X = $scope.Y
```

However, whenever scope.Y changes, looks like $scope.X changes too. Is there a way to avoid the chain? I just want to assign the value of $scope.Y once.

I tried using angular copy but it didn't work:

```
$scope.X = angular.copy([$scope.Y])[0];
```

Thanks

Comment: What about `$scope.X = angular.copy($scope.Y)`? Not sure why you were using arrays

Comment: $scope.X = $scope.Y should work...  maybe these abstract versions you posted are not the best examples. Can you please create a plunk or fiddle of your problem? Workings perfectly for me... http://plnkr.co/edit/9pdnJHcPMwIeFHIemBBO?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

angular.copy should produce a clone of the object. There are a few other methods that may be perform better, see [What is the most efficient way to deep clone an object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-clone-an-object) . I already use lodash for other stuff in my site so I use the [_.cloneDeep](https://lodash.com/docs#cloneDeep) method.